# Stopping ADB server failed (code -1). Unzip failed........ (Access is denied) - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

When i try to install the `Android SDK Platform-tools` from the the Android SDK Manager in `Android Studio` i get this error message:

`Stopping ADB server failed (code -1). Unzip failed: C:\Users\God\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe (Access is denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.`

Does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysteriously trying installing it today worked.

Go figure..

Answer (score 1):

Your operating system is denying access to some files on your computer that the SDK manager needs to access.

Run the SDK manager as an administrator and everything should run just fine.

Comment: I can run Android Studio as administrator , but how do i run the android SDK Manager as one? thank you for the answer

Comment: I recommend running the `android` executable directly. You should be able to find it in your SDK path.

Comment: Running Android Studio as admin changed nothing. I will try the other suggestion. But how do i get to that exe file?

Comment: OK - i run the SDK Manger exe file as administrator and it's still the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The same like accepted answer, but I only restarted PC and then I could install platform-tools (admin mode).

Before I installed platform-tools, I had updated SDK, and had to abort at some point. Maybe this in effect caused the problem. But that's not that important. Works, dunno why.